# ¿Cómo crear un toast desde una clase diferente a mi activity?

Tags: android, clase, android-toast

Bueno lo que yo deseo hacer es lo siguiente, crear un toast en un clase alternativa y luego llamarla en mi clase principal....

Tengo puesto este codigo pero me da error en el this...

```
public class classCoordenadasinsert {
String mensaje="Hola mundo";

public static void prueba(){
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

necesito eso para luego llamarlo aqui...

```
classCoordenadasinsert coordenadasinsert=new classCoordenadasinsert();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coordenadasinsert.prueba();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un toast necesita un contexto para poder ser desplegado en pantalla. Una clase normal no es considerada como un contexto dentro del desarollo android.

Un contexto es aquella unidad basica capaz de acceder a los recursos del sistema o de la aplicacion, por ejemplo, un acitivity o un servicio. Por ende para que tu clase funcione debe pasarle un context como parametro de entrada. Con eso en mente tu clase deberia quedar asi:

```
public class classCoordenadasinsert {
String mensaje="Hola mundo";

public static void prueba(Context context){
    Toast.makeText(context, ""+mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

y el llamado queda asi

```
classCoordenadasinsert coordenadasinsert=new classCoordenadasinsert();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coordenadasinsert.prueba(this);
}
```

Siempre y cuando este ultimo sea un activity. De esta manera la damos al método un contexto correcto el cual puede usar para desplegar el mensaje Toast

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono conrrectamente...

Comment: De ser asi por favor seleccionala como la respuesta correcta :D , muchas gracias